# Convert sql Collection to String in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to pull data from a sql query and get it converted to HTML to finally embed the results in an email body.

My code is as follows;

```
$SQLCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT SYS.Name,LDISK.DeviceID0,LDISK.Size0 AS DiskSizeMB,LDISK.FreeSpace0 AS FreeSpaceMB,SCCM.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.LastHWScan,SCCM.dbo.v_GS_LastSoftwareScan.LastScanDate
    FROM v_FullCollectionMembership_Valid SYS
      JOIN v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK LDISK ON SYS.ResourceID = LDISK.ResourceID
      INNER JOIN SCCM.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS
        ON LDISK.ResourceID = SCCM.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.ResourceID
      INNER JOIN SCCM.dbo.v_GS_LastSoftwareScan
        ON SCCM.dbo.v_GS_LastSoftwareScan.ResourceID =
        SCCM.dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS.ResourceID
    WHERE
      LDISK.DeviceID0 = 'C:' AND
      LDISK.DriveType0 = 3 AND
      ((LDISK.FreeSpace0 <= ((LDISK.Size0 * 10) / 100)) OR
        (LDISK.FreeSpace0 <= 1024)) AND
      SYS.CollectionID = 'SMS00001'
    ORDER BY
      SYS.Name"
    $SQLCommand.Connection = $SQLConnection 

    $SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand                  
    $SQLDataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
    $SqlAdapter.fill($SQLDataset) | out-null 

    $FileInfo = $SQLDataset.tables | FT -AutoSize
```

The resulting format of the data stored in $FileInfo looks good;

Name       DeviceID0 DiskSizeMB FreeSpaceMB LastHWScan            LastScanDate
----       --------- ---------- ----------- ----------            ------------
Server01   C:             53244        2010 7/28/2017 3:18:01 PM  7/28/2017 5:25:51 AM

...however when I pipe this to ConvertTo-HTML ($FileInfo | ConvertTo-HTML) the resulting format comes out like this;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd</th><th>pageHeaderEntry</th><th>pageFooterEntry</th><th>autosizeInfo</th><th>shapeInfo</th><th>groupingEntry</th></tr>
<tr><td>033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280</td><td></td><td></td><td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.AutosizeInfo</td><td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

When I look at the type of my $FileInfo I get this;

```
$FileInfo.GetType();

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                               
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

...so I suspect that the `ConvertTo-HTML` module is looking for input in string format however I can't seem to get this to work properly - even after trying options like `$FileInfo | Out-String -Stream`

I want to believe that this can be done easily - I just can't find the right approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, PowerShell cmdlets expect (data) _objects_ as input (not strings), and `ConvertTo-Html` is no exception. _Formatting_ cmdlets such as `Format-Table` (`ft`) should _solely_ be used for _immediate display_ - the output of such cmdlets is not useful for processing the data further, so assigning `Format-Table` output to the variable you're piping to `ConvertTo-Html` will not produce meaningful results.

Comment: Thanks mklement0 - I'll have to remember that about Format-Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove format-table, use select with exlude not necessary option with first table, try this

```
$SQLDataset.tables[0] |
    select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Name, Table, ItemArray | 
        ConvertTo-Html
```

Comment: That's perfect - thanks Esperento57! Now it displays exactly like I've been trying for days!